# How to Solve "error in . local object, ...) :" Error in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm quite new to RStudio and I'm trying to create an `MA Plot` out of some data that looks like this:
e.g.

| Gene Name | baseMean | log2FC | Padj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aat-1 | 1.0 | 0.222 | 0.50 |
| aat-2 | 1.0 | 0.222 | 0.50 |

and so-on.

When I use the `plotMA` function, I get the following error:

```
Error in .local(object, ...) : 
  When called with a data.frame, plotMA expects the data frame to have 3 columns, two numeric ones for mean and log fold change, and a logical one for significance.
```

Would anyone know anything that could help me?

I would also super appreciate it if anyone could help me with code to make a heatmap from this data also, as I can't seem to get that to work right now either.

Comment: If you can please provide some sample data (like the 2 rows above) and the package/code you are using to generate the MAplot it will make it easier to help you troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

Without showing how you obtained and plotted your data, this reproducible example shows how to generate an MA plot using 'DESeq2':

```
#if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
#  install.packages("BiocManager")
#BiocManager::install("airway")
#BiocManager::install("DESeq2")
library(airway)
data("airway")
se <- airway
library(DESeq2)

dds <- DESeqDataSet(se, design = ~ cell + dex)
keep <- rowSums(counts(dds)) >= 10
dds <- dds[keep,]
dds <- DESeq(dds)
res <- results(dds, name="dex_untrt_vs_trt")
res$lfcSE <- NULL
res$stat <- NULL
res$pvalue <- NULL
res
#>                 baseMean log2FoldChange        padj
#>                <numeric>      <numeric>   <numeric>
#>ENSG00000000003  708.5979      0.3812272 1.28920e-03
#>ENSG00000000419  520.2963     -0.2068403 1.94929e-01
#>ENSG00000000457  237.1621     -0.0379542 9.09901e-01
#>ENSG00000000460   57.9324      0.0885314 8.92994e-01
#>ENSG00000000971 5817.3108     -0.4264245 2.06392e-05

res2 <- as.data.frame(res) %>% 
  mutate(padj = ifelse(padj <= 0.05, TRUE, FALSE))

str(res2)
#>'data.frame': 22369 obs. of  3 variables:
#> $ baseMean      : num  708.6 520.3 237.2 57.9 5817.3 ...
#> $ log2FoldChange: num  0.3812 -0.2068 -0.038 0.0885 -0.4264 ...
#> $ padj          : logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE ...

res2
#>                    baseMean log2FoldChange  padj
#>ENSG00000000003 7.085979e+02   0.3812271582  TRUE
#>ENSG00000000419 5.202963e+02  -0.2068402621 FALSE
#>ENSG00000000457 2.371621e+02  -0.0379541749 FALSE
#>ENSG00000000460 5.793238e+01   0.0885313640 FALSE
#>ENSG00000000971 5.817311e+03  -0.4264244587  TRUE
#>ENSG00000001036 1.282101e+03   0.2410430437  TRUE
#>ENSG00000001084 6.098887e+02   0.0475900022 FALSE

plotMA(res2, ylim=c(-2,2))
```

[image: example_1.png]

--

Based on this reproducible example, your data looks to have some differences that need to be addressed before the function will accept it (assuming you're using `DESeq2::plotMA()`).

First, the 'Gene Name' column should be rownames, not a column in the dataframe:

```
rownames(dataset) <- dataset[,1]
dataset[,1] <- NULL
```

And you'll also need to change the Padj column to 'logical' (as indicated by the error):

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset2 <- dataset %>% 
  mutate(Padj = ifelse(Padj <= 0.05, TRUE, FALSE))
```

Then, unless there are other issues, the dataset will plot:

```
plotMA(dataset2, ylim=c(-2,2))
```

--

Here is an example of plotting the top 20 genes as a heatmap:

```
#install.packages("pheatmap")
library(pheatmap)
# use the log transform on the data set
select <- order(rowMeans(counts(dds,normalized=TRUE)),
                decreasing=TRUE)[1:20]
df <- as.data.frame(colData(dds)[,"dex"])
rownames(df) <- colnames(assay(dds)[select,])
colnames(df) <- "Dex" 
df$Dex <- sort(df$Dex)
pheatmap(assay(dds)[select,], cluster_rows=FALSE, show_rownames=FALSE,
         cluster_cols=FALSE, annotation_col=df)
```

[image: example_2.png]